# svcutil.exe => Cannot obtain Metadata from https://....................svc?wsdl

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, model-view-controller

I have to use an **.SVC** WebService in my MVC project. When I want to add the service through **Add Service Reference**, then I get the following error:

> There was an error downloading https://.............svc/$metadata'.
>   The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I tried generating my required classes to use the service with the following command in CMD:

> svcutil.exe https://.............svc?wsdl

But I get the following error message:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from https://.............svc?wsdl

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you open that url in a browser, what happens? Are you sure that service is hosted on a secure protocol?

Comment: @rene, When I open that url in browser it shows me a page containing some tips regarding generating my required files using svcutil.exe. I have followed the tips and now generated two files. One file is a .cs file and the other one is output.config. What should I do now? How can I call my service and use its methods?

Comment: add the .cs file to your project file (add existing file if you're in Visual Studio) and "merge" the content of output.config into your web.config. That should compile and give you some "Client" class that sits in that .cs file which you instantiate and call its methods to invoke the operatons of the service.

Answer (score 0):

The aforementioned error mainly indicates that we should trust the server certificate before we download the service metadata.
As @rene mentioned. After we have generated the client proxy class, we could instantiate the class to invoke the method like calling a local method.
But we also could invoke the service by adding service reference, which is a built-in feature in VS.
[image]
Here is an official guideline, wish it is useful to you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.